# WCF Data Services Primary Key

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

I'm using WCF Data Services, but when I'm creating a new object:

```
MyObject.CreateMyObject();
```

It requires a primary key, but in my mapping(using code first), the primary key is auto-increment.

How could I do ?

Here is my generated reference code:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Services.Design", "1.0.0")]
    public static View CreateView(int idView)
    {
        View view = new View();
        view.IdView = idView;
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Never had the specific case of the WCF Service situation, but perhaps the default value could apply for an `int`, which is of course `0`. This works for Linq2Sql en EF4, so not entirely sure about your situation.

Comment: We are working with int-only primary keys, for performance improvements, which in my opinion is lame. So I'll need to fake a primary key in my wcf data services, but i take the mapping key, which is my int key... here is the problem.